# Lightswitch 2013 HTML App (VB) dump Application.User.FullName in to global variable or something

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've been trying for days to figure this out but I'm not having any luck. I have an app I'm writing that will be deployed to Sharepoint 2013 (cloud). In server side code it is very simple to get info info about the current user and have these values inserted in to records, use it for query parameters, etc. This is my first app and aside from the learning experience everything is going smoothly until I started to tweak my "main menu". I need to get the name and possibly a few other details about the user running the app. The app uses Sharepoint authentication, not Windows or forms.

I need the user name available on the client side because it will be used to address various parameters on the main menu. I've searched for days and tried everything I can think of but I've hit a wall. Being so new to this doesn't help. All the examples I've found assume that some other kind of authentication (forms in particular) is in use. I do not store user info in the database at all.

I'd be really grateful if anyone can give me a clue. I really thought this would be easy, but it's turned in to the hardest thing.

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your existing code?

Comment: I'm not sure what to post. I have something like  Public CurrentUserName = Application.Current.User.FullName in a class but that is only from messing around. I have this and I've tried adding a data item to the HTML screen (string) and setting the value to the CurrentUserName value. Clearly it doesn't work.